# Unexpected change to CBP form 3299 for import of unaccompanied articles

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

I am in the process of completing the CBP form 3299 for import of unaccompanied articles as a non-resident and noticed some changes to the form that I wasn't expecting.

The [form provided by UPS](https://www.ups.com/media/en/free_articles.pdf) contains the following option in part II 10. C (but is dated October 1995):

> All articles of apparel, personal adornment, toiletries and similar personal effects for which free entry is sought were actually owned by me and in the possession of myself, or those members of my family who accompanied me, at the time of departure to the United States and that they are appropriate and are intended for our personal use and not for any other person nor for sale. (9804.00.20 HTSUSA)

The [current form from the CBP website](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2019-Nov/CBP%20Form%203299.pdf) (which is dated November 2019) however only refers to "household effects":

> All household effects acquired abroad for which free entry is sought were used abroad for at least one year by me or my family in a household of which I or my family was a resident member during such period of use, and are not intended for any other person or for sale. (9804.00.05, HTSUSA)

Do you know why this form has changed and how I should declare "personal effects" rather than "household effects" as a non-resident?

Comment: You could look up the CFR sections cited on the form and see if they have changed.  All changes to federal regulations are published in the Federal Register.

Comment: It looks like 9804.00.20 is still valid (see https://hts.usitc.gov/?query=9804) but I'm not quite sure how to declare those items on the form.

Comment: Hi @TillHoffmann did you figure it out in the end? If a non-resident (someone moving into the US for the first time) imports personal effects ONLY (without household effects), does it mean we leave Part IV section D blank (because there's nothing checked in Part IV sections A., B., C.)?